# How to control zoom level of product images in Magento?

Tags: magento, zend-framework, magento-1.7

Some product images on my Magento based ecommerce website are not of high quality. So when using default zoom functionality of Magento product images become blur which is not a good experience for website visitors.

Is there any way by which zoom level of images can be controlled in Magento?

Comment: which extension you are using for zoom

Comment: Default zoom function of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

it is depends on your magento version used in application:

In Community edition have it is zoom stored in `js/varien/product.js` (Product.Zoom object)

And IN Enterprise it is in `/skin/frontend/enterprise/default/js/jqzoom`

I assume that your scripts are loaded perfectly.

The problem would be with "image size" vs "image-frame" size. If your product image is less or equal then dimensions of an html element (set in css for CE), then product zoom functionality will not performed (no use of extra large image of bad quality).

So check size of your image. Or just upload really big one to solve your issue.

let me know if i can help you more.